# Delete project using BIM360 API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have created a project using 
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/projects
and activate it. 
Is there any option to DELETE the created project? 
I have already seen that archiving via Patch is available.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [REST API design style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), The HTTP method for deleting something will implement via `DELETE`. Unfortunately, it's not available in BIM360 HQ API currently.